# Constructing Truth Tables for Formulas with Variable Valuations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, computer-science, first-order-logic

I was solving a problem from old exams and got stuck here. I'd appreciate the help.

We have the three variables p, q, and r. There are 8 valuations of the variables. If F is a propositional logic formula containing p, q, and r, and we construct a truth table for F, the table will thus have 8 rows.

Provide a formula F with the variables p, q, and r that is true for the valuations

$${ \lbrace p : F, q : T, r : F \rbrace, \lbrace p : T, q : T, r : F \rbrace, \lbrace p : T, q : F, r : F \rbrace }$$

and is false for all other valuations.

I drew a truth table and got an answer which goes:
$((p⋁q⋁r) ⋁ \neg (p⋁q⋁r)) \to ((r \to p) ⋀ r)$

BUT this took a lot of time to the point I started to think is this even how we are supposed to solve this problem. There has gotta be another way than just playing with the truth table given the fact that we have a short time for the exam.

My question: Is there another easier way to solve it? If not, how do I find an easier formula and faster?

Comment: I presume you mean there are 3 cases: one where $p=F, q=T, r=F$; one where $p=T, q=T, r=F$; one where $p=T, q=F, r=F$? It's hard to interpret a flat comma-separated list. Can you clarify this?

Comment: @PrimeMover You are right it is latex/ dollar signs that removed my curly brackets but fixed now!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this, assuming the list of cases is interpreted the way I believe it ought to be, is as follows.

The expression is true when:

- either $p = F$ and $q = T$ and $r = F$
- or $p = T$ and $q = T$ and $r = F$
- or $p = T$ and $q = F$ and $r = F$.

We're practically there.

We just express it symbolically as:

$$(\neg p \land q \land \neg r) \lor (p \land q \land \neg r) \lor (p \land \neg q \land \neg r)$$

This is now in **disjunctive normal form**, and is one of the standard forms in which an arbitrary propositional logical statement can be expressed.

It is possible to simplify it considerably, for example and for a start by factorising $\neg r$ out using distributivity rules.

EDIT: Decided to complete the job, as follows:

Hence we get:
$$((\neg p \land q) \lor (p \land q) \lor (p \land \neg q)) \land \neg r$$

Then we notice that: $(\neg p \land q) \lor (p \land q) \lor (p \land \neg q)$ just means "false when both $p$ and $q$ are false.

That is: $(\neg p \land q) \lor (p \land q) \lor (p \land \neg q)$ is the same as $\neg (\neg p \land \neg q)$, which by De Morgan is just $p \lor q$.

Hence what we get at the end is:
$$(p \lor q) \land \neg r$$

Edit 2: For clarity, here is the truth table:

$$\begin {array} {|ccc|c|c|c|} \hline p & q & r & p \lor q & \neg r & (p \lor q) \land \neg r \\ \hline 
F & F & F & F & T & F \\
F & F & T & F & F & F \\
F & T & F & T & T & T \\
F & T & T & T & F & F \\
T & F & F & T & T & T \\
T & F & T & T & F & F \\
T & T & F & T & T & T \\
T & T & T & T & F & F \\ \hline \end {array}$$

Comment: But your solution is not false for all other cases than the ones mentioned. According to truth table I made it is also true for when {p:F, q:T, r:F}.

Comment: @Need_MathHelp But it's *supposed* to be true for $\{p=F, q=T, r=F\}$. That's given as true by hypothesis.

Comment: Sorry I mean something else, I accidentally had put a T where it didn't belong and got me 4 True cases. You are right and thank you so much for taking the time to help me, I appreciate it!